# Get the value in a nested Bson document directly (VB.NET)?

Tags: mongodb, vb.net, nested, element, bsondocument

I am trying to get the value of an element in a nested Bson document using MongoDB driver.
The document outline is something like this:

```
_id  >> 1-4OUKQQ
type >> person
name >> john
surname >> blogg
details >> { "sid" : "456", "height" : "1.8m"}
```

I would like to "get the value" of "height" which is a nested list of elements in the document.
I would like to do something like

`mHeight = element.details.height`

and get a value of "1.8m"

without the need to do expensive looping to find the value of element = detail.height

n/a please see above.

Comment: A good deserialization library should support it, assuming the correct destination class definition.  I'm not familiar with the available tooling for what you're doing, so I don't know if it's actually set up for that.

Comment: if you use .net driver, then it should be: element["details"]["height"]

Comment: @dododo For VB, that would almost certainly be `element("details")("height")`.

Comment: might be, in other words, you should use indexer in what ever way VB allows doing it